# How to fire a rule only if other rule has been fired?

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine, business-rules

Let's say I've two rules-

`rule1` will be fired if `conditionA` and `conditionB` are satisfied.

`rule2` will be fired if `conditionC` and `condition` D are satisfied.

I want to write a `rule3` which should be fired if rule1 and rule2 have been fired? Ideally I would like to be able to use operators e.g.-

`fire rule3 if rule1 **AND** rule2 have been fired`

```
fire rule3 if either rule1 **OR** rule2 has been fired.
```

In other words, how do I refer to a rule's firing in another rule?

I can obviously use conditionsABCD in rule3 but I am sure there must be an elegant way to handle this scenario.

Ideally, I want to keep rule1, rule2 and rule3 in one DRL file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a fact on rule1 when conditionA and conditionB are ok named rule1ok and the same for rule2 with rule2ok.
Then you can check the new conditions rule1ok and rule2ok for rule3.

Comment: Thanks, that could be one way to go. Though I am hoping to keep my model classes clean and not include rule information in them. I would love to entertain any other ideas- I am hoping Drools itself has some sort of construct which allows to refer a rule's firing in the rule language itself

Comment: @gauravphoenix You can define facts inside DRL if you don't want to modify your domain classes.

Comment: As @zenbeni says, just create minimal types in DRL for inference. A good explanation of this can be found here: http://blog.athico.com/2010/01/drools-inference-and-truth-maintenance.html

Comment: Just to be clear, to "add a fact" I used the `insertLogical(Object)` in my RHS of my DRL. Make sure you know to use either `insert()` or `insertLogical()`, based on this documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.1.0.Final/drools-docs/html/DroolsLanguageReferenceChapter.html#d0e9267

Answer (score 0):

One of four best practices I always teach is that rules should not invoke or reference other rules.

When you have rules referencing other rules, your rules get bogged down in implementation details and cease to be solely focused on your policy.

One of the other best practices is that rules should not duplicate the conditions of other rules.

So... @zenbeni's answer above is good advice. You could consider what it means in your policy model when rule1 is true and derive a new fact in the model based upon that. Same for rule2.